# Current on a one file edit system

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to setup my site so that when I edit one file it edits all the header or footer. but with the header I there is a current, can someone give me a script so that it will add:`<li id="current" class="grey active item1">` infront of the "`<a href`" and if it isnt currently "active" it will add: `<li class="grey item26">` infront of the "`<a href`", would prefer this in PHP but javascript would be fine aswell.

Sources for you to look at if you need any more info:

www.isgclan.com

www.isgclan.com/test.php

www.isgclan.com/template/main/header.php

The file that starts all this is just:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require('template/main/header.php');
    require("template/partnerscontent.php");
    require("template/main/footer.php");
?>
```

Comment: The question isn't clear. Perhaps you could give an example of the before HTML and an after HTML.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it is a active menu item related question...

When you include/require files they inherit the scope of where they were called from. See [Variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

So from test.php you could set a variable

```
$active = 'test';
```

And then in the header.php file you can check that variable

```
<li <?php 
if ($active == 'test') 
    echo 'id = "current" class="grey active item1"';
else
    echo 'class=""grey item26"' 
?>>
```

Then in other files you can set $active to something else and have that handle this.

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick reply was very helpful. Took me a while to understand it though as I am very noobish with PHP.